# Furchtbar vs. fürchterlich

Tags: difference, adjective

*Furchtbar* und *fürchterlich* haben die gleiche Herkunft wie *Furcht*, aber verschiedene Suffixe. Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen diesen Wörtern? Ist etwas furchtbares etwas, das fürchterlich sein kann, aber nicht zwangsläufig ist?

Comment: You can't use *beide* as a translation for "both" in this case. Use *sowohl... als auch...* (a little sophisticated), or just leave the *beide* out altogether. BTW, are comments like these welcome, or should I just shut up? (there are also other mistakes in your first sentence, but this immediately jumped out at me as a *false friend*)

Comment: @fzwo: Thanks, I'm very grateful for every correction. Feel free to edit my post to fix any mistakes, however minor they may be. I'm happy if people edit my posts to make them sound more German, even if the original is grammatically correct.

Comment: @fzwo and everybody which speaks a fluent German: I want to stress that *yes*, corrections are a real treat to every student of German participating on this site! Though most often it's not necessary with a comment, a simple edit will suffice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die beiden Wörter sind sich in ihrer Bedeutung sehr ähnlich. "Fürchterlich" hat jedoch einen leicht echauffierten/affektierten Unterton, so dass "furchtbar" etwas ernsthafter klingt.

> Es ist furchtbar, wie viele Menschen unter der Armutsgrenze leben.
>
> Jetzt mach doch endlich diese fürchterliche Musik aus!

"Furchtbar" ist jedoch universell und kann "fürchterlich" immer ersetzten.

> Jetzt mach doch endlich diese furchtbare Musik aus!

Ich würde sogar soweit gehen zu sagen, dass "fürchterlich" ein wenig altmodisch klingt. Das Klischee-Bild, das sich dazu in meinem Kopf bildet, ist eine entrüstete ältere Dame mit Hut. ;) Dementsprechend ist wohl auch eine der häufigsten Verwendungen:

> Er hat sich fürchterlich darüber aufgeregt.

Comment: +1 für den Beispielsatz mit _furchtbar_ - da würde _fürchterlich_ nicht gut passen.

Comment: @ladybug: Die Damebeschreibung war hilfreich, um die Konnotationen zu verstehen.

Comment: ich fand sie etwas unhöflich, aber werde sie wieder einfügen. ^^

Comment: "etwas universeller" könntest du mit "universell" austauschen, oder bin ich zu pingelig? ;)

Comment: Umpf. ^^ Kannst du sowas nicht einfach selbst korrigieren? :p

Comment: Ja, das stimmt! Das nächste Mal dann. ;-)

Comment: Ich möchte das etwas abmildern, und sagen, dass 'fürchterlich' einen affektierten Ton haben kann (den aber auch 'furchtbar' haben kann - man muß sich entsprechende Tante einfach beim 'furchtbar'-sagen vorstellen)*. Aber wenn man die Wirkung etwas abmildern will, dann sagt man eher 'fürchterlich'. Aber es ist nur eine Nuance. *)Ich meine micht sogar an einen Kabarettisten zu erinnern, der sehr nasal minutenlang 'fuuuuurchtbar!' wiederholt hat. Von der Lippe? Oder so ein anderer, korpulenter, der in der Anstalt ab und an auftaucht.

Comment: Stimmt, die Trennlinie ist tatsächlich sehr fein. Man sollte sie nicht überbewerten.